# Sonarqube API limited to return 10000 issues

Tags: sonarqube

```
Sonarqube version: 7.6.0
```

I am using following Sonar api:

```
http://mysonarurl.com/api/issues/search?pageSize=500&pageIndex=20
```

I have over 87K issues. Above api doesn't return more than 10K issues. I am getting error once I try to increase the pageIndex parameter to 21. The error message i get is `"Can return only the first 10000 results. 10500th result asked."`

Is there anyway I can get all the 87K issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get more than 10,000 issues on sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857995/how-to-get-more-than-10-000-issues-on-sonarqube)

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at the database yourself and maybe create a query, but of course there is no official support for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think query to db is needed due to limitations in API.